# adding cocoapod dependencies to a cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode6, google-plus, cocoapods

I’m trying to work out how to add cocoa pod dependencies to an iOS app that has an embedded cocoa touch framework. I have my podfile set up like this:

```
link_with [‘TestApp’, ‘TestAppFramework’]
platform :ios, '8.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.7'
```

Then I add a view controller with a sign in button as per the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

and everything compiles with no problems. If I then run the app it will start up and display a google plus sign in button, but I get a lot of warnings about the google classes being defined in two places, for example:

> objc[6727]: Class GPPSignIn is implemented in both /Users/jamesburke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-eiqrhcijoqplxgaoodgtwzncvhjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestAppFramework.framework/TestAppFramework and /Users/jamesburke/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/730A1805-D46F-4D11-9F9E-DA37C1147F9A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EB7EE52A-7FB6-45CE-81B4-1E9A45875E69/TestApp.app/TestApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

If I then click on the sign in button I get an error saying that I haven’t set the google client id - which I have, but because the GPPSignIn class relies on a shared instance it looks like the duplicate classes have confused things:

> 2014-11-24 20:54:25.557 TestApp[6727:155282] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GPPSignIn|'

Looking in the stack trace we flip from the TestApp scope to the TestAppFramework one, even though there’s no code in the framework at this point

```
…
3   TestAppFramework                    0x000000010c7f1a9c -[GPPSignIn assertValidParameters] + 77
4   TestAppFramework                    0x000000010c7f35e7 -[GPPSignIn authenticateMaybeInteractively:withParams:] + 118
5   TestAppFramework                    0x000000010c7f5ac8 -[GPPSignInButton buttonPressed] + 164
6   UIKit                               0x000000010b4c38be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
…
19  UIKit                               0x000000010b4c2420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
20  TestApp                             0x000000010a25e9f3 main + 115
```

I get this problem with some other cocoa pods, for example mailcore2-ios, but some other pods don’t seem to raise the same warnings.

Is there a way to set my podfile up so that both my framework and my app have access to the same dependencies, but without clashing at runtime? Or should I just not be setting my dependencies up like this?

Answer (score 0):

The link_with should be used for (correct me if I'm wrong) linking targets within the same project. What you are describing is an embedded framework (which is a separate project).

What you actually want to do is adding the dependencies to the embedded framework like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

workspace 'TestApp.xcworkspace'

def import_pods
    pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.7'
end

target : TestAppFramework do
    xcodeproj 'TestAppFramework.xcodeproj'
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    link_with 'TestAppFramework', 'TestAppFrameworkTests'
    import_pods
end

target : TestApp do
    xcodeproj 'TestApp.xcodeproj'
    platform :ios, '8.0'
    link_with 'TestApp', 'TestAppTests'
    import_pods
end
```

This example adds the google sdk to both projects (and linking to their test targets), maybe you only need it in the embedded framework.

Comment: Thanks for that, but adding the google sdk to both targets would result in the error I showed above.

What I actually found worked in the end was moving all of the code for the app into the framework - so the app delegate, all the storyboards, all the view controllers etc. are in the framework, and the main app just becomes an empty holder. One thing to note with that - if you try to do the same thing with a share extension then cocoapods can't handle it, you have to have a dummy view controller in the extension so that cocoapods can still work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.7' supports Framework. 
In your podfile

> ```
> target 'YourProjectName' do
> pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.7'
> end
> ```
>
> Try to use it like this.